Is a color palette from an image a derivative?
If color extraction algorithms are run in an image (eg. K-means clustering), the color palette obtained from the image is a derivative work?

Not for copyright law
I mean, it is clearly derivative in the sense that it couldn’t exist without the original, but it is not a derivative work for copyright law because it is not a literary or artistic work. Instead, it is a collection of facts about the original work in the same way that a table counting all the words used in a novel is.
